# How can I call client side function from server?

Tags: html, typescript, express

How can I make that if sql query is empty then it does this alert on top of the browser. I tried installing "alert" and it worked but I cant change its UI.
I have this funcion on html  but I don't know how to call it from my server side script.

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
```

This is my server side code right now

```
connection.query(SQL QUERY) {
            if(err) throw err
        if (rows.length <= 0) {
            alert("This is not what i need")
        }
```

Comment: @NVRM I can't design this alert box.

Comment: My main problem is how can I call client side function from server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `alert` server-side, because the server does not have a window object.

You should send a message to the client and then call the `alert` function there.

And besides that, you can't change the UI of the alert dialog box because it's defined by the browser.

Comment: Yes, I know. And could you tell me how can I call this myFunction from server side?

Comment: There are multiple ways to communicate between the server and client.
I see you're using express, check out this guide: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-response-from-server-to-client-using-node-js-and-express-js/

Comment: But isn't there a particular command to call client side functions from server side? Like res.send(myFunction()) ormsth.

Comment: No, you have to send a response/event to the client-side. Then client-side you listen for that response and call `alert`